# XFCE: how to remove "Always on top" option

Tags: xfce, user-interface

When I click the program link in the bottom panel among the other options I have "Always on top". Once I accidentally clicked it for audacios, and now it's always active by default. So, every time I launch it I have to right click upon it's block in the panel and untick "Always on top".

Is it possible to disable this option - I never use it, and it just wastes my time.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, `audacious` has its own option for staying above other windows, which IIRC is only be accessible when running in the Winamp classic interface mode. This option is independent of the window manager managed capability.

If you are talking about `xfwm4` (the window manager) option for keeping any window on top of others, you might have not noticed that the window menu labels changed (in English locales it should be something like *"Always on Top"* and *"Same as Other Windows"*):

[image] [image]

You can also have a key-binding for this action (again, I'm not sure if that is the default, but it *might* be something like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F*x*</kbd> (with *x* probably between 6 and 12).